# Объясните конструкцию условия javascript

Tags: javascript

Не пойму, что проверяет конструкция js:

```
if(!''.replace(/^/,String))
```

Больше конечно вызывает вопрос второй параметр String.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вторым параметром вы можете передать функцию, которая возвращает строку. Стандартное поведение для `String() // ""`. В данном случае, если переопределено стандартное поведение для обьекта String (String() не вернет пустую строку, то данное условие даст отрицательный результат)

Comment: Я не очень силен в javascript. Каким образом может быть переопределено стандартное поведение объекта String?

Comment: Ну в данном случае, что вы просто где то не переприсвоили переменной String новую функцию.

Comment: Это чужой скрипт. Просто не могу разобраться. Он выдает нужный результат, т.е. значение истинно, но я не понимаю почему. Если String (именно с заглавной буквы) нигде не переопределяется, то логическое выражение  в данном случае должно вернуть ложь.

Comment: Стандартное поведение для функции String - вернуть строковый примитив - параметр, который вы передали (если без new).  
`String()` вернет пустую строку. `String('hello')` вернет 'hello'.

У вас, происходит вставка в начало строки результата выполнения функции, переданной вторым аргументом (в функции replace). В данном случае, если вы не меняете обьект String, это будет пустая строка. 

То есть в пустую строку вставится пустая строка. Будет пустая строка, которая преобразуется в ложное значение, а оператор "!" преобразует в true.

То есть вы всегда будете получать true.

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно. Если всегда будет true зачем городить эту ерунду с replace.

Answer (score 0):

Странная конструкция.
String - это переменная. Если она пустая String = '', то условие выполняется.

Comment: А String не может в данном случае быть конструктором? В скрипте нет переменной String.